# tensorflow package RStudio Cloud, Error: could not find a Python environment for /usr/bin/python3

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, package, environment

I am trying to install tensorflow to be able to work with an lstm time series prediction in R. When running the third line I am getting the error below. I have python3 installed in /Users/theresasporn/Desktop/CareerApp/env/bin/python3. Even when stating the environment path/python path it still gives me the same error. Does anyone know what I can do to make this work? Any kind of help is appreciated!

```
library(reticulate)
reticulate::use_python("C:/Users/theresasporn/Desktop/CareerApp/env/bin/python3/")
reticulate::use_virtualenv("C:/Users/theresasporn/Desktop/CareerApp/env/")
install.packages("tensorflow") #works
library(tensorflow) #works
install_tensorflow() #error
```

```
Error: could not find a Python environment for /usr/bin/python3
```

I am getting the same error when trying it with keras instead of tensorflow.

Comment: give python env path in your script?

Comment: See [here](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/versions.html) for a guide ohw to configure your python path. The `reticulate::use_python` function allows you to specify a python version at run time, or by setting User environemnt variable `RETICULATE_PYTHON`. So in your case `reticulate::use_python("C:/Users/theresasporn/Desktop/CareerApp/env/bin/python3/")` might be the correct solution.

Comment: Thank you @Oliver and sahasrara62, even if I specify the python/environment path it doesn't work (see updated question)...

Comment: For me, it works creating a Conda environment outside R, from the console, and then using that Conda environment with reticulate. Something like `library(reticulate);
use_condaenv("env_name", required = TRUE)`. Install any dependencies to the conda environment outside R.